# Using jdbcauthentication and saml2 authentication in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am developing a Spring boot web application. I want to use SSO with SAML2 firstly. After user authenticate successfully with saml2, I want to use jdbcauthentication to check if the email address which we got after saml2 authentication exists in my database and also get role of the user who has above email address.

I have searched many topics on the Internet but the results are either jdbcauthentication or saml2 authentication. That's not what I expect. I want use jdbcauthencation with the email address after saml2 authencation before.